# Reallocated Sector Count Field

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, bad-sectors

My hard drive performance is very slow, startup time has been long and harddisk led is on at most of time.

HD Tune shows that there is not any bad sector in my hard disk, but it has a **Reallocated Sector Count** problem.

**Bad Sector Report:**
[image]

**Health Report :** 
[image]

Is there any solution for solving this error?

Comment: The only solution to the reallocation sector count failure is the replacement of the hardware itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relocation means that there are bad sectors in your HD, but disk companies has a limited solution for that. They reserved some sectors at the disk to replace these bad sectors so these bad sectors are relocated, and instead of these bad sectors the reserved sectors are used. But as time goes on these bad sectors will increase and all the reserved sectors  will be used.

Then you will start to face bad sector problem.

There is simply no solution for that, you can continue to use this hd for some more time at your own risk. But eventually the disk will be unusable. So I would recommend you to backup the data at the disk ASAP, then it is up to you to continue to use the disk or not.

By the way now your disk getting slower, as it needs more time to reach the data at the relocated sectors.

Comment: of course, you true! But HD Tune didn't show any bad sector after analysing ! (see the first snapshot in my question)

Comment: Of course your HD has bad sectors, but as hd relocated these bad sectors, they are not visible to you. But as the reserved sectors for reallocation are all used, this reallocation can no longer continue, and hd will start to mark bad sectors instead of relocate them.

Comment: Ohh... Ok! I Think I most buy a new Hard Disk! thanks for help!