# Hard Disk SMART returning high values after being wiped

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I bought some used 2TB hard drives that have been wiped, and upon receiving the drives, I've run a quick test on it with SMART reporting three warnings (the drives have identical warnings):

- Reallocated sector count raw value: between 17 million an 93 million
- Current pending sector raw value: 28,147,495 (same value across the drives)
- Offline Uncorrectable raw value:  28,147,495 (same value across the drives)

A proper business sold the drives with a description on the invoice of "Condition: 100% Health 100% Performance Tested with Hard Disk Sentinel 5.50 PRO".

Are these three errors significant? How can I force the firmware to clear these warnings if they are not legitimate(somehow induced through the wiping process)?

[image]

Comment: Try another SMART tool (preferably from the manufacturer) as the values may be being misinterpreted

Comment: [Very](https://superuser.com/q/26842/432690) [significant](https://superuser.com/q/619927/432690). But there is something fishy. `Temperature_Celsius` twice? I would expect attribute `190` to mean `Temperature Difference` or `Airflow Temperature`. Its raw value is unreal. `Power_Cycle_Count` is very low, many other values are very high. Is the drive connected directly (SATA?) or via some bridge (USB enclosure?)? The advice to try another tool is reasonable.

Comment: This was a SMART printout from a QNAP NAS. It's a Seagate enterprise hard disk so I'm guessing it was used in a corporate NAS, which might explain the power cycle/hours disparity. The seller has a whole lot of these drives.

Comment: Raw values may be split within 48 Bits of space as Max/Min/Actual. So if you are using Windows use a tool like CrystalDiskInfo and in Menu Function -->Advanced Features --> Raw Values Set the display option as 10 Dec 2 and check again.

Comment: @WhatTheJ: I suggest you use SeaTools to check the drive

Comment: Seatools SMART tool just either gives a PASS or FAIL. Mine is a PASS with nowhere I can seem to find more information on the readouts.

Comment: @patkim using Crystal, the 10Dec2 for Current and uncorrectable sector count gives 65535 65281 0 ; hopefully it's min current max!
The Reallocated sectors returns 21760 1024 0

Comment: Selling worn out drives, nice.

Comment: Generally for parameters like Reallocated, Pending, Uncorrectable Sector etc the Raw values are Max/Min/Actual. In your case it appears that actual is zero. Also the Normalized value still has not fallen. Disk goes bad generally when the normalized value falls below the threshold. I suggest you additionally run SeaTools Long Test which will test each and every sector for its health and tell you the overall status. If long test passes then in theory you should be good to go. The test could be destructive and may run for 2 - 3 hours on 2 TB disk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the comments on the main; I tested with SeaTools and all I got was 'Pass' with no details. Tested with CrystalDiskInfo and didn't get any pink/red lines although the crazy raw count was still present. Would have liked to understand the funny numbers more but I think I'm ok with 2 SMART tools returning a thumbs up.